# SQL bring back highest sum of rows

Tags: filter, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

I'm looking to calculate the highest basket in my set of data but I can't get my head around how I should do it.

I have data like:

```
OrderID | CustomerID | BasketID | ProductID | Price

1 | 1 | 1 | 221 | 10
2 | 1 | 1 | 431 | 123
3 | 1 | 2 | 761 | 44
4 | 2 | 3 | 12 | 54
5 | 2 | 3 | 102 | 78
6 | 3 | 4 | 111 | 98
7 | 3 | 4 | 41 | 45
8 | 3 | 5 | 65 | 66
9 | 4 | 6 | 32 | 47
10 | 4 | 6 | 118 | 544
```

Sorry if it seems quite messy.

But I can easily get the SUM with an obvious

```
SELECT SUM([Price]), BasketID, CustomerID FROM table
GROUP BY BasketID, CustomerID
```

But how can I filter the list for only the highest priced Basket ID for that CustomerID

Thanks

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, sorry about that, must've forgot to put it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY BasketTotal DESC) AS RNK
        FROM   (SELECT Sum(Price) AS BasketTotal,
                       BasketID,
                       CustomerID
                FROM   Order a
                GROUP  BY BasketID,
                          CustomerID
                          ) a

       ) b
       WHERE RNK = 1
```

I managed to conjure something up that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
;WITH HighestPricePerCustomerAndBasket AS
(
   SELECT 
       ID, UserID, ClassID, SchoolID, Created,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BasketID,CustomerID ORDER BY Price DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT 
   [Price], BasketID, CustomerID
FROM HighestPricePerCustomerAndBasket
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

This CTE "partitions" your data by `BasketID,CustomerID`, and for each partition, the `ROW_NUMBER` function hands out sequential numbers, starting at 1 and ordered by `Price DESC` - so the first row (highest price) gets `RowNum = 1` (for each `BasketID,CustomerID` "partition") which is what I select from the CTE in the SELECT statement after it.